# How to customize Spring Security StandardSession.isValid() logic. Need max session time and skip request logic for IST

Tags: java, spring-security, tomcat7

I have a Java/Tomcat/Spring/Spring Security w/CAS application and I have two product requirements that I'm trying to figure out how to meet:

1. The users HTTP/Authentication session must have a max timeout.  Only want the session valid for X amount of time, even if the user isn't idle.  I know how to change/set the idle timeout, but there doesn't appear to be support for a max session time.
2. I need to be able to have certain requests not reset the idle timeout. Our GUI client polls the server frequently for updates and I want to exclude these requests from the idle session time out logic.

I have looked through the Spring Security docs and source and I found Tomcat's implementation of the HttpSession, StandardSession.  In it is a call to isValid().  It looks like if I derived a new class from StandardSession I could could add my custom logic to the isValid() check for both Max Session time and idle session skip.

My question is, "Is this the correct way to add this custom logic?"  If so, then what I haven't been able to figure out is how to tell Tomcat to use my new Session object instead of it's own.  Is this even possible?  In Spring I would update my application config with a new bean then wire this bean in to the class that creates sessions. However, I don't know what the process is for the servlet files.

I've seen may questions on both these two subjects but none of them are java, Tomcat, spring framework, spring security based.  I know if I wasn't using spring, or spring security then I'd have to implement a custom filter.  Since I'm using spring security I'd assumed that I need a spring security specific answer.

My environment:
SUSE 11 SP1 Linux

Java v1.7

Tomcat v7

Spring Framework v3.2.2

Spring Security v3.1.4

Don't know if this matters but I'm doing CAS authentication but with the JAS-CAS client which means I've configured Spring Security to do pre-authenticated authentication.